# Is it possible to have more than one java class for one Activity on android?

Tags: java, android, class, android-activity

My code in the java class for an activity has become lengthy.

I'm basically writing a lot of animation codes to illustrate a concept.

Is it possible to have more than one java class for an Activity on android ?

Comment: Short answer : yes, OOP is all about that. But in order for us to help, you'll need to add details/code.

Comment: Yeah I got it now. Now it looks like a silly question to me.

Comment: Don't beat yourself up, we all had to learn what we know, at some point ;)

Comment: If your actual code works, and you want to have it reviewed and get suggestions on how to restructure it, you can post it at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Yes. Thanks. Just created another class and its done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

You can break apart the code in whatever way you see fit - that's the benefit of an object oriented language. You can feel free to create a whole class dedicated to graphical animation or similar, and call its methods from your `Activity`. In fact, modularizing logical units of your project is a good step towards a better design and more readable code.

Comment: @Gissipi_453 Not silly at all. Many newer programmers never even consider this possibility. But that's what OOP is all about. Good luck!